# Can't delete data from Realtime Database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I am locked in Firebase in the following situation.

I have a collection in Realtime Database called My_Collection containg a few documents (About 5). When in the web Firebase console I am unable to delete any element in the collection (by clicking on the Trash icon as usual).

When I go to see Rules playground an try to simulate what I want to do:

I see: Simulated write allowed

I believe the rules should not matter in this situation, but this is only to clarify the circumstances.

And I have no web site active that could automatically regenerate the documents.
I think I have never seen this before.

Any idea on how to solve this problem (How to delete the documents?) will be very welcome.

Comment: The Firebase console is not affected by security rules, so those shouldn't matter. Is there any error message in the developer console of your browser?

Comment: Indeed those shouldn't matter. But I still should be able to delete what I want. I do not see any error message. But just to be sure I am not overlooking any detail, where exactly do I see these messages you are referring to. I am using Firefox.

Comment: Did you try to use Chrome, for example?

Comment: No. I basically only use Firefox and Brave.

Comment: I also noticed that if I have another collection along side My_Collection, I hit the same issue, I can't delete anything inside.

Comment: I just discovered that if I hold down the SHIFT key when doing the delete then it works. Life if the message showing up otherwise was causing trouble.